# How important is "Gorilla glass" in a smartphone?

Tags: screen, physical-damage, screen-protector

My phone's glass has cracked over time, and I'm planning to replace it. I've noticed that a lot of the models I'm considering to replace it with (and my current phone itself) don't feature "Gorilla Glass".

My question: How significant is the lack/presence of "Gorilla Glass"? Are other covering glass types simply unbranded and not as well known, but similar in resistance to shocks/bending - or does "Gorilla Glass" really have a significant advantage?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the usage of your device. It's just a extra layer of protection and comes with some advantages over others *(Like scratch resistance, splash proofing)*.

> If your phone has a soft back cover and a glass protector on top of
>   the screen then dropping it from a table or bed won't hurt that much
>   but your phone will get some scratches on the body. Mild pressure like
>   carrying your device inside your pocket or under the pillow or inside
>   a bag won't affect. Corning Gorilla Glasses actually passed several
>   drop tests, tension tests, scratch tests.

You can trust [Gorilla Glass](https://www.corning.com/gorillaglass/worldwide/en.html) because they don't make glasses only for smartphones. They also make glasses for industries. Corning is the company who manufacture Gorilla Glass.

> So, answer to your question is it's not significant at all. You must
>   replace it with other unbranded screen protections. You must have to
>   check the relaiabilty of that product before using it. And that's
>   where brand recognition comes into place. Corning will provide you
>   warranty on specific products. And because many users already used it
>   so you can obviously trust them.
>
> Choice will be yours. If you able to make the right purchase no matter
>   it's branded or not it'll always worth.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "usage"? I carry it around in a soft shell and a screen protector, but it does take some pressure, rubbing, and once in a while - a fall from tabletop-level or lower.

Comment: I corrected the answer and if it helped you then upvote it.